# How is the ISP internet speed divided among devices on a LAN?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I was having a hard time finding information on this.

I would like to know how data is shared/divided. For example if I am paying for 1Gb down/up internet speed and 10 devices are requesting to download really large files like games. Does each device get a allocated a certain amount max speed or how does it work?

Another example is if I have a security camera uploading video nonstop and a someone is streaming video to viewers.

Any info would be appreciated

Comment: Not a full answer, but this is basically down to your router. I use a Netgear router where I can configure which devices get which percentage of data and priority. If you are talking about how your ISP shares bandwidth, you'd have to check with them.

Comment: Your question does not mention Wi-Fi, but your tags include "wireless-networking".  Are you referring to Ethernet, Wi-Fi, both, or something else?

Comment: Yes I meant Ethernet and WiFi on a LAN.

Answer (score 3):

> For example if I am paying for 1Gb down/up internet speed and 10 devices are requesting to download really large files like games. Does each device get a allocated a certain amount max speed or how does it work

In this situation it's not per-device at all, it's (mostly) per-connection.

Networks are packet-based. If packets arrive at a router faster than they can be sent out through their outbound links (for example, if packets from a web server arrive at the ISP's router faster than it can push them through your WAN connection), some of them will end up being delayed (queued at the router) and possibly dropped.

Most transfers (except for live video streams) are done using TCP, which has built-in congestion control. The sender doesn't keep transmitting packets without limit – after a certain amount of packets, if they are not "acknowledged" by the receiver, it would pause and wait until they are. (If you look at a packet capture in Wireshark you will see each upload or download accompanied by a continuous flow of ACKs; it is why you require some upload speed in order to download anything.)

So when a packet is lost and therefore not ACK'd, the sender's congestion control algorithm will cause it to slow down. As a result, each TCP connection self-adjusts until it consumes *almost* the available bandwidth (without going over and causing packet loss), and the congestion control algorithms are designed to be "fair" so that concurrent connections end up being roughly in balance. It works the same way for multiple connections from the same device as it does for multiple devices.

[Note: This is a *very rough* explanation because frankly I do not understand half of it either.]

> Another example is if I have a security camera uploading video nonstop and a someone is streaming video to viewers.

A live video stream (RTMP/RTSP/VoIP) is somewhat different from a file download. When downloading a file, usually all data is already stored and available up-front so the sender can go as fast as its storage allows (which is *usually* fast enough to saturate a Gigabit connection, even if sending from an HDD), whereas a live video stream produces data at a roughly fixed rate (the bitrate configured in the audio and video codecs) and will generally not use more even if available.

So if you watch a security camera stream via RTSP, and send your own stream to a central server via RTMP (e.g. OBS to YouTube), then both your stream and the security camera's stream only consume a few Mbps each – they're regulated by the codecs – and the rest of your 1 Gbps stays available.

(Though note that *watching* a live stream on YouTube is somewhere in the middle between the two modes, as it doesn't use RTSP but actually functions by downloading individual video chunks in quick succession – so while the *average* bandwidth over time is still roughly the same, it's used in brief bursts rather than a continuous stream. And of course VODs are no longer "live" at all, so it's even more bursty, with the player pre-buffering large chunks at a time.)

Comment: That's an interesting insight on encoded bitrate for stream-able A/V media files.

Comment: It actually wasn't about *files* at all, but about truly live streams; stream-able files are somewhat in-between the two behaviors.

Answer (score 2):

> Does each device get a allocated a certain amount max speed ...

No, there is no allocation or divvying up of the "speed".
Rather the transmission medium is shared using time multiplexing. Information/data is always transmitted at a fixed speed in units of packets/frames. Only one packet is transmitted in each direction at a time. The available time for using the medium is divvied up by simply transmitting packets. The transmission of each packet/frame will consume a finite amount of time on the wire (or WiFi channel) based on packet/frame length and the fixed transmission rate.
The duplexing mode would determine if simultaneous transmit&receive is allowed.

The transmission medium is shared using time multiplexing. Even though the transfer was performed with packets sent at a fixed transfer speed, when you calculate the "transfer speed" for an individual transfer, you are actually calculating an *averaged* data rate over time. You can end up with an appearance that the "*ISP Internet speed*" is somehow shared among the users. It's just a numeric illusion because you're ignoring the fact that the "transfer speed" is a number that is an average.